# Postgresql: Find which table a specific record in an inherited table belongs to

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

Considering the case in which we've got two tables, say: `SubscriptionPayments` and `OrderPayments` inherit the shared table `Payments`.

Is there a way to find out within the table `Payments` which table any record belongs to; in other words, is it possible to indicate whether a record in `Payments` is a part of `SubscriptionPayments` **without** joining?

### Edit:

I've already thought of joining, casing, and even adding a discriminator column.
There must be some metadata relating inheriting tables to their base, so I thought there might be some metadata that indicates what record belongs to which table, something like a built-in discriminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's [`tableoid` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-TABLEOID), meant exactly for that:

> `tableoid`
> The OID of the table containing this row. This column is particularly handy for queries that select from partitioned tables (see [Section 5.11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html)) or **inheritance hierarchies** (see [Section 5.10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html)), since without it, it's difficult to tell which individual table a row came from. The `tableoid` can be joined against the `oid` column of `pg_class` to obtain the table name.

[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/4Y5S_aM_)

```
create table "Payments"(id int);
create table "SubscriptionPayments"() inherits ("Payments");
create table "OrderPayments"() inherits ("Payments");
 
insert into "Payments" select 1;
insert into "SubscriptionPayments" select 2;
insert into "OrderPayments" select 3;
select * from "Payments";
```

All records in `Payments` do appear to be indistinguishable even though *all* columns were requested:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

That's because by default, system columns are hidden unless explicitly listed, so you need to add `tableoid` to the list. It's a (not very readable) [`oid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html), but it can be converted to the actual table name by casting to [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE):

```
select tableoid, tableoid::regclass, * from "Payments";
```

| tableoid | tableoid | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16384 | "Payments" | 1 |
| 16387 | "SubscriptionPayments" | 2 |
| 16390 | "OrderPayments" | 3 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the discriminator column for this purpose